# Python to slice a dataframe to many excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to split a dataframe into many excel files, using its row value's name for files' name

Sample dataframe

```
    account_key    State
0    111            NY
1    111            CA
2    222            NJ
3    888            WE
4    888            TL
```

Expected result:

The first excel file's name is **account_111.xlsx**, and the data in it is

```
account_key    State
 111            NY
 111            CA
```

the Second excel file's name is **account_222.xlsx**, the data in it is

```
account_key    State
222             NJ
```

my code doesn't give me the expected result

```
names = df['account_key'].unique().tolist()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path + 'my.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for myname in names:
    mydf = df.loc[df['account_key']==myname]
    mydf.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()
```

by the way how to modify the code to rename the worksheet from "sheet1" to "myNote" while looping ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, just use `to_excel` in `groupby`

```
for acc, g in df.groupby('account_key'):
    g.to_excel(f'account_{acc}.xlsx')
```

If your have an older version of python which does not support `f-strings`, use

```
for acc, g in df.groupby('account_key'):
    g.to_excel('account_{}.xlsx'.format(acc))
```

To name the worksheet, just pass the name as second argument

```
g.to_excel(f'account_{acc}.xlsx', 'myNote')
```

Comment: can you explain what the g stand for in the for loop? thanks

Comment: @Learn the `groupby` will group your dataframe according to the `account_key`s you have. When you iterate over this groupby obj, `acc` gets the value of the name of the groups (in this case, the values in  `account_key`) and `g` is a data frame that contains only ths corresponding `acc`. I named it `g` after `group`, but you can name it something else if you think there is a more appropriate/intuitive name ;)

Comment: @RafaelC one additional question, how to modify your code to rename each worksheet from "sheet1" to "myNote" while looping ?  thank you , your code is amazing short

Comment: @Make_A_Living Thanks! Just add the name as second argument, check the edit ;)

Comment: @RafaelC invite you to answer my touch question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938729/python-search-corresponding-data-in-multiple-excel-and-paste-to-a-new-excel-work