# Python search corresponding data in multiple excel and paste to a new excel worksheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

i have some excel files in a folder, there's already a worksheet call "service" in each file

```
Notes_111.xlsx
Notes_222.xlsx
Notes_888.xlsx
```

**Workflow** : I want to open each .xlsx file, for example, Notes_111.xlsx, then add a new worksheet, name as "code_city", then based on file's name **111**, extract only the **code = 111** data from the master dataframe and paste to the new worksheet. then save.

Sample master dataframe in another excel file

```
    code           city
0    111            NY
1    111            CA
2    222            NJ
3    888            WE
4    888            TL
```

i don't know how to write a logic within a loop to search corresponding data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
from openpyxl import load_workbook

for f in glob.glob(path + "Notes_*.xlsx"):
   wb = load_workbook(f)
   ws = wb.create_sheet('code_city')
   ws['A1'] = 'how to search corresponding data and paste here???'
   wb.save(f)
```

please help.

Comment: What do the sheets in the files look like?

Comment: @CharlieClark there's an excel file has 1 sheet, look like the above sample master dataframe. The workflow is to open Notes_111.xlsx, add a new sheet, then based of the file's name 111, it will extract only the code=111 in the master data frame, then paste code and city in that new sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas its much easier to manipulate, I believe it uses openpyxl under the hood anyway.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os


for f in glob.glob('Notes_*.xlsx'):
    dda = re.findall('\d+', f) #matches digits in the filename

    df_each = pd.read_excel(f) # have to save the data first, coz ExcelWriter will clear up and create a new excel, so, you paste the saved data back to new sheet
    df_1_dda = df_master[df_master['code'] == int(dda[0])] #select only those records with code in the filename

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f)
    df_each.to_excel(writer, 'service', index = False) #  paste the saved data back to new sheet
    df_1_dda.to_excel(writer, 'code_city', index = False)
    writer.close()
```

Hope that helps!

using python 3.6.4 Anaconda - 32-bit

Comment: Don't work, keep in mind, I save the master sheet as a  dataframe df_master

Comment: Updated for master df

Comment: for some reason, using "   code_to_search_by = name.split('_')[1]" this way doesn't work, I modified your code to make it fully work, Thank you !!

Comment: hmm weird, it works for me...what version of python are you using? If i helped you out, please upvote or check off as answer :) have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

for f in glob.glob("Notes_*.xlsx"):
    code = re.findall('\d+', f) #matches digits in the filename
    df_1_dda = df_master[df_master['code'] == int(code[0])] #select only those records with code from the master dataframe

    #create new worksheet using openpyxl
    wb = load_workbook(f)
    ws = wb.create_sheet('code_city')
    wb.save(f)

    # reload the file and paste data I need
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f)
    df_1_dda.to_excel(writer, 'code_city')
    writer.save()
```

Comment: my own answer has an issue,  the new df will replace my old df data